# Strange issue adding strings together in Jython Sikulix

Tags: python-2.7, jython, sikuli

So I'm writing a program in Jython SikuliX to automatically make labels by taking a three letter input (MAG) and then adding a number to the end (1) and then increment the number by +1 for each label (MAG1 - MAG2 - MAG3 etc.)

However the trick here is that I need the combination of the letters and number to always be 6 characters in length (So MAG001 or MAG010 or MAG100).

I've already got the number concatenation down however I'm running into a strange issue with any number over 100. Going from label 9 to label 10 and above works perfectly (MAG009 - MAG010 - MAG011 and so on) however when I get to MAG99 and then go to MAG100 I receive an error:

```
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first line: module ( function ) 
statement 26: main ( name_change ) name = name
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

I have no idea why this is... Code is below.

```
import time

name1 = str(input("First three letters of product name"))
labels = int(input("At what number do you want the labels to stop?"))

a = int(input("What number should the labels start at?"))
e = "00"
d = "0"



find("1496686601617.png")
doubleClick("1496686607803.png")

def name_change(name1, a):
    a = str(a)
    c = len("%s%s" % (name1, a))

    if c == 4:
        name = ("%s%s" % (name1, e))

    if c == 5:
        name = ("%s%s" % (name1, d))

    if c == 6:
        name = name

    a = int(a)
    return name

def label_make(name, a):
    click("1496688531026.png")
    type("0000")
    rightClick("1496688447045.png")
    click("Select_All.png")
    type("%s%r" % (name, a))
    click("1496686753618.png")
    click("Save As-1.png")
    time.sleep(1)
    type("%s%r" % (name, a))
    click("1496687258684.png")

    a = a + 1
    return a 

while labels >= a:
    name = name_change(name1, a)
    a = label_make(name, a)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved my own issue:

I went back to an older version that didn't involve functions and specified the variable for name if it is already 6 characters long and it works. Code below:

```
import time

name1 = str(input("First three letters of product name"))
labels = int(input("At what number do you want the labels to stop?"))

a = int(input("What number should the labels start at?"))
e = "00"
d = "0"



find("1496686601617.png")
doubleClick("1496686607803.png")

while labels >= a:
    #a = str(a)
    c = len("%s%s" % (name1, a))

    if c == 4:
        name = ("%s%s" % (name1, e))

    if c == 5:
        name = ("%s%s" % (name1, d))

    if c == 6:
        name = name1

    #a = int(a)


    click("1496688531026.png")
    type("0000")
    rightClick("1496688447045.png")
    click("Select_All.png")
    type("%s%r" % (name, a))
    click("1496686753618.png")
    click("Save As-1.png")
    time.sleep(1)
    type("%s%r" % (name, a))
    click("1496687258684.png")
    #a = int(a)
    a = a + 1
```